# Archlinux forum question doesn't seem answerable

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, terminal

I'm trying to register for the [Archlinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/register.php), and they have a question at the bottom that verifies that you're using Linux:

```
What is the output of "date -u +%V$(uname)|sha256sum|sed 's/\W//g'"?(Required)
```

The answer I gave was:

```
31b5001da5e8fcaa06cc3d8db96331e80cf1488f443dfc500581133a63e396ea
```

I tried on Ubuntu and Arch and got the same result. No dice. Here are some of the pieces (that seem to be working):

```
$ date Wed Jun  5 15:16:05 UTC 2013

$ date -u +%V$(uname)
23Linux
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? If not, who should I contact about this?

Comment: Well, someone actually involved with the arch Linux forum perhaps?

Comment: +1 Same result here. Are you sure they don't mean you to run this on an Arch Linux installation? And could you link to the relevant page?

Comment: Looks like somebody has asked "Are you capable of running a Linux forum?" ...

Comment: @l0b0 updated question with link to the registration page. Also, I actually did try both Arch and Ubuntu just in case.

Comment: @terdon since I can't register for the forum, I don't think there's a way for me to make any noise over there (no "contact us")

Comment: Does it work if you try again? I tried twice with the same answer and the second time it randomly worked

Comment: @MichaelMrozek yes. Odd. I tried it several times, but using FF back button to re-submit the form. Re-submitting the form after the validation check seems to work for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Surely this will be resolved soon, but in case anyone else encounters this problem before it's resolved, the answer is:

1. submit the form
2. do not press the browser's back button
3. re-paste the answer into the form
4. re-submit the form

Comment: Seems like functionality intended for people who hate it when people frequent their public web forums...

Comment: It's actually functionality that prevents the otherwise overwhelming volume of spam that plagued us for several months, sucking up huge amounts of the time people who run the boards volunteer...

Comment: there's probably a better way to mitigate spam than presenting the user with a seemingly broken form.